# PyCharm: Cannot connect to postgres-db in docker container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, pycharm

as the title says, I'm having trouble to connect a rather simple database-configuration with my IDE PyCharm.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
db:
  restart: always
  image: postgres
  container_name: db
  volumes:
    - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  networks:
    - db-net
```

Using it with django, here are my database-settings from the backend, which are working perfectly fine:

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "postgres",
        "USER": "postgres",
        "PASSWORD": "postgres",
        "HOST": "db",
        "PORT": 5432,
    }
}
```

But when trying to connect the database inside PyCharm with the following settings, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Note: *The field for password was of course filled -> get's cleared everytime someone hits Apply or tries to test the connection.*

Does anyone might know what I'm doing wrong or maybe had the same problem?

Thanks for your help and have a great weekend!

Comment: In the host field , you are using the value db right ? Just change to localhost and try

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi: Still receiving the same error.

Comment: URL: postgresql://localhost:5432 try this